# Run terminal/login shell when desktop is stuck

Tags: terminal, command-line, desktop, login-screen

Is there a way to run terminal/login shell in case your desktop became unresponsive and you need a terminal to try fix it, i.e. kill some problem process?

It seems that >console user doesn't work anymore in Big Sur.

Comment: The >console user was only available at login. So how are you going to bring up a login prompt when the desktop is unresponsive? Can you provide more details of when you would do this, and what you're trying to fix? There may be another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to have a separate admin account for such cases so you can log into that one and terminate whatever process is stuck on your main account.

When the GUI is hung, force quitting apps is less preferable than using ssh to remote in from a phone, tablet or another computer. You would only have fast user switching as another “work around”.

Comment: Sounds good, I will consider this one. But isn't there a way to do it without desktop/gui?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to keep the Terminal running always, so that in the event of one app locking up, I can usually switch to the Terminal somehow.

But it's very rare in MacOS for the entire UI to freeze up.

If this is happening regularly, then I'd suggest trying to diagnose and fix the problem so that it doesn't happen, rather than 'managing' it after the fact.

Comment: The problem is I can't open terminal neither switch to it, as Desktop UI in some unknown freeze state. Being able to login into system without loading Desktop or at least login as separate user (@nohillside answer) seems like convenient tool. It would make testing M1 and different type of software a little bit easier.

Comment: @sunprophit Yes, but as I say, if the Desktop is frozen, how are you going to bring up a login window?

Comment: Desktop is unresponsive, but getting to a lock screen via lock/AppleID key works. There I tried to login using `>console`, but seems it doesn't work anymore. In general I think about Linux analogy, when it's possible to run login shell via keyboard shortcut even when something bad has happened with desktop manager